# Are there any resources about the PHP XMLWriter functionality?

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

The PHP documentation can be found [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php), but I think it's rather lacking. There are no examples of how to use these functions, and few (if any) of the pages have user comments. So where might I be able to find an explanation (and example code) on how to use these functions to write an XML document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any other resources, but I found the examples in the comments on [this page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.xmlwriter.php) quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at the [DOM functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) over the SimpleXML ones - it's much more robust. Not as *simple*, but definitely has more features.

Comment: Simple XML is not the same thing as XMLwriter. XMLwriter wraps the libxml xmlWriter API.